# retrieve messages in a topic using kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I have written a python script using `kafka-python` library which writes and reads messages into `kafka`. I write messages without any problem; I can retrieve them using `kafka` console tools. But I can't read them using my python script. I have a for on my consumer which freezes on the first line of the iteration and never returns. Here's my code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    "my-topic",
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092"),
    value_deserializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode("utf-8")
)

for msg in consumer:
    print(type(msg))
```

The consumer is created and subscribed completely; I can see that `my-topic` is listed on the topic list of its `_client` property.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, kafka python start from last offset, ie will only read new mesages.
One approach is to read from beginning or the alternative approach is to keep polling topic in an infinite loop as shown in below code:

```
while True:
    try:
        records = consumer.poll(60 * 1000) # timeout in millis , here set to 1 min

        record_list = []
        for tp, consumer_records in records.items():
            for consumer_record in consumer_records:
                record_list.append(consumer_record.value)
        print(record_list) # record_list will be list of dictionaries
```

### Edit

To read from the beginning, we need to add `auto_offset_reset=earliest` earlies while making consumer object

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    "my-topic",
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092"),
    value_deserializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode("utf-8"),
    auto_offset_reset='earliest')
```

Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for explanation; would you please give me an example of reading from beginning? That suits my case more.

Comment: I have added an example of reading from the beginning. Hope this helps!!